# Given that $3\mathsf P(A\cap B)=2 \mathsf P(A'\cap B) = \mathsf P(A'\cap B')$ and $\mathsf P(A\cap B)=3/5$, what is $\mathsf P(A\mid B')$?

Tags: probability

$A$ and $B$ are two events such that, $\mathsf P(A\cap B)=3/5$.

Given that $3\mathsf P(A\cap B)=2 \mathsf P(A'\cap B) = \mathsf P(A'\cap B') = x$. Find $\mathsf P(A\mid B')$.

Attempt:
$$P(B')=P(A \cap B')+P(A' \cap B')$$

Considering the conditions given
$$3P(A \cap B)=P(A' \cap B')$$

Therefore 
$$P(A' \cap B')=3P(A \cap B)$$

But $P(A \cap B)=\frac 35$.
thus $P(A'\cap B')=3\times\frac35=\frac95$

This is where I am confused after getting a probability which is greater than $1$.

Comment: What have your tried so far?  You will get better response if you include your own working.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

$$\begin{align}\text{By definition of conditional probability:}
\\
\mathsf P(A\mid B') &= \dfrac {\mathsf P(A\cap B')}{\mathsf P(B')}
\\
\text{By the Law of Total Probabitity:}
\\ \mathsf P(B') & = \mathsf P(A\cap B')+\mathsf P(A'\cap B')
\\ \mathsf P(B) & = \mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(A'\cap B)
\\
\text{By definition of complementary probability:}
\\ \mathsf P(B') &= 1-\mathsf P(B)
\end{align}$$